# How to insert date wise data on x-axis of Flotcharts line graph library?

Tags: jquery, mysql, graph, linechart

i have included three line graphs for showing the number of articles posted on daily, weekly (current week), and monthly(current month) basis. I have fetched an array from my database having two columns, one is the date column, and the other column holds the number of articles posted on that particular date. Now i need to display this data on a line chart with dates on x-axis and number of articles on y-axis. I don't know how to render dates on x-axis, i know there's a plugin in this library for this purpose but I am not so sure. Any example for this scenario would be much appreciated. Please help :(